# parallel ContractnetResponder and Contractnetresponder

Tags: agent, agents-jade

I develop a multi-agent system based on the contract net protocol to the communication between agents.
My system is composed of one supervisor agent and n machine agents.
The supervisor agent launches a CFP to find the appropriate machine to perform a given task. 
Each machine agent answers to the CFP and it adds the task in its queue if its proposal is accepted by the supervisor agent. At the same time each machine agent launches a CFP to other machine agents where the aim is to exchange tasks that are in its queue (tasks accepted).

I implemented on the supervisor agent the ContractNetInitiator behaviour.
I implemented on the machine agentthe ContractNetreponder behaviour.

Now, how I must implement the CNP between machine agents. I think to do as follow about behaviours:

```
ParallelBehaviour PB = new ParallelBehaviour();

PB.addSubBehaviour(new Responder(this, null)); //ContractNetresponder behaviour
PB.addSubBehaviour(new initiator(this,60000));  //ContractNetinitiator behaviour
addBehaviour(PB);
```

My question: in the responder behaviour, the machine agent receives the CFP from supervisor agent and from other machine agents. Can I use one ContractNetresponder and  filter later the incoming messages or I must create two ContractNetresponder  behaviour to handle the CFP separately.

Thank you for your answering or any orientation.
Best regards

Comment: Of course using reply.getSender() to decide what to do in the Responder create a confusion and my system does not work.
I have tried to create two paralle responder behaviors that Implement ContractNetResponder: one to answer the CFP of the supervisor agent and the other to answer the CFP of vehicle agent. In this way my system does not work   too , it blokes, the supervisor agent don’t receive any responses to their cfp.
Are there any suggestions , best regards

Comment: No, I have not a code on public repository, and I have many classes so It is so long to put it here! If you can give me your Email to send you or this is my Email lmdfarida@yahoo.fr, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use message features (like sender, performative, content) to filter incomming messages.

About the use of parallel behaviors, it seems you are doing well. You may reproduce some case to try to figure out what is going on with your code. The example showed by [Jean Vaucher and Ambroise Ncho](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vaucher/Agents/Jade/primer6.html) may be a way to do it:

```
Acheteur2.java

   int        bestPrice = 9999;
   ACLMessage bestOffer = null;

   protected void setup() 
   {
      ACLMessage msg = newMsg( ACLMessage.QUERY_REF ); 

      MessageTemplate template = MessageTemplate.and( 
            MessageTemplate.MatchPerformative( ACLMessage.INFORM ),
            MessageTemplate.MatchConversationId( msg.getConversationId() ));

      SequentialBehaviour seq = new SequentialBehaviour();
      addBehaviour( seq );

      ParallelBehaviour par = new ParallelBehaviour( ParallelBehaviour.WHEN_ALL );
      seq.addSubBehaviour( par );

      for (int i = 1; i<=3; i++) 
      {
         msg.addReceiver( new AID( "s" + i,  AID.ISLOCALNAME ));

         par.addSubBehaviour( new myReceiver( this, 1000, template) 
            {
               public void handle( ACLMessage msg) 
               {  
                  if (msg != null) {
                     int offer = Integer.parseInt( msg.getContent());
                     if (offer < bestPrice) {
                        bestPrice = offer;
                        bestOffer = msg;
               }  }  }
            });
      }
      seq.addSubBehaviour( new OneShotBehaviour()
          {
             public void action() 
             {  
                if (bestOffer != null) 
                     System.out.println("Best Price $" + bestPrice );
                else 
                   System.out.println("Got no quotes");    
             }
          });

      send ( msg );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answering mr "Cleber Jorge Amaral" that help me a lot.